# Convert joda date time

Tags: java, jodatime

I have a string like `"2007-03-12T04:27:00.000+01:00"` and i want to convert it to datetime object and do some calculations. currently i am using `joda.time`. when I convert this to joda DateTime object  and try to print it is displaying as `"2007-03-12T08:57:00.000+05:30"`. how can i print the value with the same time zone.

Comment: Timezone is different value is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you specify the time zone you want, DateTime defaults to the machine local time zone.  The [DateTime(Object)](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#DateTime%28java.lang.Object%29) constructor uses the offset to figure out what instant you mean, but it doesn't use the offset to set the time zone.  So instead of:

```
    DateTime localDateTime = new DateTime("2007-03-12T04:27:00.000+01:00");
```

parse the offset and get the DateTimeZone that is appropriate, and give it to the DateTime.

```
    DateTimeZone zone1 = DateTimeZone.forOffsetHoursMinutes(01, 00);
    DateTime localDateTime = new DateTime("2007-03-12T04:27:00.000", zone1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// get current moment in default time zone
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
// translate to London local time
DateTime dtLondon = dt.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Time Zone ID here"));//Europe/Paris
```

You can find detailed list of Time zone Id [here](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html)

Comment: Here the Timezone is not fixed. it can change. so i cannot hardcode TimeZone ID in the code. is there any way to read the timezone id from the date string(it is having +01:00 at the end)